# How to apply the result and index of the result of max() to an array on a single line

Tags: matlab

I was given a problem in MatLab where I needed to write a single line of code that starts with

```
variableName =
```

and find the max value of a 2d array and it's index. I don't use matlab at all, and this seems infuriatingly simple in any language I know. I know to get the value & index of the result of max, you do something like

```
[M,I] = max(stuffToCheck)
```

I just dont understand how to assign the array that creates to a variable name. I've spent some time googling but this feels like a very weird constraint so I haven't found anything yet. How do I do this on one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the variable you want to assign the result:

```
[variableName(:,1),variableName(:,2)] = max(stuffToCheck)
```

its the only way because in matlab if you write :

```
variable = function();
```

matlab return only the first output, to get other ouput you have to write:

```
[output1,output2,...] = function();
```

Comment: Note if it's a 2D array you may want to put `stuffToCheck(:)` to get a single max value.